# Toshiba Satellite A 655 wifi switch doesn't work network disabled after 16.04 update

Tags: 16.04, wireless, toshiba

I have read through many of the posts and none help. Looking for someone to run through the steps one on one. Thank you in advance.

```
       *-network
            description: Ethernet interface
            product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
            vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
            logical name: enp1s0
            version: 05
            serial: b8:70:f4:57:de:ca
            size: 10Mbit/s
            capacity: 100Mbit/s
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
            configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
            resources: irq:24 ioport:6000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
      *-network DISABLED
            description: Wireless interface
            product: Centrino Advanced-N + WiMAX 6250 [Kilmer Peak]
            vendor: Intel Corporation
            physical id: 0
            bus info: pci@0000:06:00.0
            logical name: wlp6s0
            version: 5f
            serial: 00:23:15:cf:db:f8
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 33MHz
            capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
            configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.4.0-47-generic firmware=41.28.5.1 build 33926 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
            resources: irq:28 memory:d4600000-d4601fff


*-network DISABLED
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx64d4da23e6fb
       serial: 64:d4:da:23:e6:fb
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: driver=i2400m_usb firmware=i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf link=no
```

rfkill

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: yes
1: i2400m-usb:1-1.6:1.0: WiMAX
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide more information?  What have you tried so far?  Do you see your device listed in output from `lshw`?  If so, include output for that device.

Comment: Run `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `rfkill list` and edit your question with the output of both of them.

Comment: Is this a dual boot system?

Comment: No, stand alone

Comment: 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
 Soft blocked: no
 Hard blocked: yes
1: i2400m-usb:1-1.6:1.0: WiMAX
 Soft blocked: yes
 Hard blocked: no

Comment: If the pushbutton between the speakers with the wifi symbol on it does not activate wireless, you should create a bug report against package linux, you can start [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug)  I have a Toshiba M645 and that button works and I see no reason why the upstream kernel developers can't get it to work on the A655